# BizTalk MDN received: An error occurred when validating an AS2 message. Make sure the certificates used have not timed out or been revoked

Tags: certificate, biztalk, biztalk-2016

This issue is occurring with only 2 Existing Trading Partners are now receiving this error.

[image: An error occurred when validating an AS2 message. Make sure the certificates used have not timed out or been revoked]

I found the following [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/an-error-occurred-when-validating-an-as2-message?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but I not know how to validate bullet points 1-3. For the rest, I did validate the following

1. Verify that there is not a broken chain of intermediate certificate authorities. (Issuer + Subject Match)
2. Verify that the certificate has not timed out. (Valid 7/6/2018 - 2021)
3. Verify that the certificate has not been revoked (there is no CRL property)
4. Verify that the certificate used for signature verification is stored in the Local computer/Other People store (it is under other people for both servers for the local computer store)

**The most annoying part is I only get this error receiving the MDN and not any other documents from the partner.**

PS
Using Biztalk Server 2016

**UPDATE**

I did fix the issue with one partner using version 3 certificates by deleting their certificate from all the stores and adding it back based on the latest one they sent.

- The other partner uses a V1 certificate and biztalk can only resolve it via adding the thumbprint manually. Based on how this is resolved I could imagine there being an old certificate cached somewhere on the server that is not in the other people store which could cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the certificates in Certificates Control Panel.

For 2, The Valid From properties are right on the General tab.

For 1 & 3, it depends on a few things, mostly whether or not you're using self-issued certificates and if the server is acting as it's own CA.  If not, you'll have to ask the issuer if the Certs are revoked.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my comment about the article wasn't very clear, bullets 1-3 in the article were:
1) Verify that the signature wrapper in the AS2 message is valid. If not, determine why the message was signed improperly by the encoder.

2) Verify that the private key used in the signing process and the public key used in the signature verification process match.

3) Verify that the Key Usage property of the certificate used for signing and signature verification is set to "data encipherment". 

Now i did fix the error for 1 of 2 partners by deleting and re-adding their certs.